# Why mongodb timeseries document is not expiring?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

Got the following timeseries schema but the documents in the timeseries collections is not expiring.

The documents are getting created but they are not getting deleted post expiry. Would like to understand what's wrong. Thanks

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import {PROVIDER} from './document.types';

@Schema({
    timestamps: true,
    timeseries: {
        timeField: 'time',
        metaField: 'market',
        granularity: 'seconds'
    },
    expireAfterSeconds: 4000
})
export class RateTickerEventData {
    public _id: string;

    @Prop({required : true})
    public provider: PROVIDER;

    @Prop({required : true})
    public market: string;

    @Prop({required : true})
    public time: Date;

    @Prop()
    public last: number;

    @Prop()
    public ask: number;

}

export const RateTickerEventDataSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(RateTickerEventData);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the nestjs part, but enter the mongo and check whether the TTL is set up correctly at the level of the database itself. Run the following from the shell/mongo IDE you use:

```js
db.getCollection('yourCollectionName').getIndices()
```

Check that the index created on the time series field (timestamp or something) has a properly set expiration

Comment: Hey, so tried db.getCollection('yourCollectionName').getIndices(), getting a empty array [].

Comment: So there are no indices defined in this collection, since ttl in mongo is defined on index, obviously the definitions you've shown in the question didn't work...